# How can I Train a Functional Keras Model with Large Amounts of Image Data and Metadata?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying out the HAM10000 challenge and I have gotten some things nailed down such as building a Functional Model for the first time, categorizing, etc. What I haven't gotten figured out is how to train my model with both image data and patient metadata. Before I talk any further, here is my model structure so that you may understand what I'm trying to do here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppQkm.png

What the model is doing is that it takes an image and passes it through several convolutional and max pooling layers, and then flattens it. The model also takes in patient metadata which include age, sex, location of pigment, etc. These values are then concatenated together and passed through three dense layers and out comes the output of the model with 7 categories (akiec, bcc, bkl, df, mel, nv, vasc).

This is the code for the model:

```
# Imports
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
import os

# Prevents CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED errors
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(gpu_options=tf.compat.v1.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.50))
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(session)

# Temporarily adds Graphviz to PATH
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz/bin/'

# Loads metadata dataset
metadata = pd.read_csv("data/HAM10000_metadata.csv")

# Removes Lesion ID column
metadata = metadata.drop(["lesion_id"], axis=1)

# Loads translation key into memory
translation = json.loads(open("data/translation.json").read())

# Translates all non-numerical values into float64 values
metadata = metadata.replace(translation["dx_type"])
metadata = metadata.replace(translation["localization"])
metadata = metadata.replace(translation["sex"])

# "Shaves" off some data to make the model generalize better and to optimize memory usage
metadata = metadata.drop(metadata.iloc[:9300].index)

# Separates Image IDs and Labels to different variables
image_id = metadata.pop("image_id")
label = metadata.pop("dx")

# Converts metadata
metadata = np.array(metadata)

# Initializes image features set
image = np.zeros((len(image_id), 450, 600, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

# Iterates through extracted image IDs list and places RGB values into image features set
for i in image_id:
    image[int(np.where(image_id == i)[0])] = np.array(Image.open("data/HAM10000_images/{}.jpg".format(i)))
    print("data/HAM10000_images/{}.jpg Loaded | {:.5}%".format(i, str(100 * float(np.where(image_id == i)[0] + 1) / len(image_id))))

# Data dtype Changing
image = image.astype(float)
label = label.astype(float)

# Categorizing Variable Initialization
new_label = np.zeros((len(image_id), 7))

# Categorizing Reformatting
a = 0
for i in label:
    if i == "akiec":
        new_label[a] = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    if i == "bcc":
        new_label[a] = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    if i == "bkl":
        new_label[a] = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    if i == "df":
        new_label[a] = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
    if i == "mel":
        new_label[a] = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
    if i == "nv":
        new_label[a] = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
    if i == "vasc":
        new_label[a] = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
    a += 1

# Convolutional Branch
image_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(450, 600, 3))
conv2D_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(8, 8), activation='relu')(image_input)
max_pool_1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2))(conv2D_1)
conv2D_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(8, 8), activation='relu')(max_pool_1)
max_pool_2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2))(conv2D_2)
flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(max_pool_2)

# Metadata Branch
metadata_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,))

# Concatenated Branch
concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([flatten, metadata_input])
hidden_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(concat)
hidden_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(96, activation='relu')(hidden_1)
hidden_3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(hidden_2)

# Model Creation
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax')(hidden_3)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[image_input, metadata_input], outputs=[output])

# Prints structure of model
plot_model(model, to_file='model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)

# Model Compilation
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss="categorical_crossentropy")

# Model Training
model.fit(x=[image, metadata], y=new_label, batch_size=32, epochs=100000, validation_split=0.2)
```

I can successfully pass in the metadata with fit(), but passing in image data is the hardest part. When I try to load roughly 9000 images' RGB matrixes (600x450 resolution) onto system memory with a dtype of float64, my PC obviously crashes. I was, however, able to succeed with this technique with a much smaller amount of images loaded to memory (roughly 100), but it is not enough data to make an accurate model. I have tried to ImageDataProcessing, but the issue is that it doesn't seem that fit_genearator() can't accept my metadata data.

One person has told me to "Create a pipeline that would load images one at a time(or in batches) as the model needs it." The problem with this is that I couldn't find much helpful documentation that can do this.

If you have a solution to this dilemma, I am all ears.

Thanks!

Comment: try `tf.Data.Dataset` or just call `fit` in a loop with smaller portions of files (read 100 files, create data, call `fit`, read next 100 files, create data< call `fit` ...)

Comment: for everytime I call `fit`, do I still have to specify the `validation_split` and `batch_size`?

Comment: You can specify validation split. But better to prepare validation data separately and call `model.evaluate()` in the end of every epoch. Your `batch_size` equals to default batch size, so you can not specify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the answer in the comment might work, whenever you're trying to pass this amount of data, you should go for **DataGenerator**. This is the best way to optimize your training.

From there you have two possibilities, either you can use the provided [ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) from tf2(keras)

In your case it doesn't seem to work, that's fine if the data are not simple, then you should create your own generator : [link](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly)

You custom DataGenerator will then look like this :

```py
class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.images = ...
        self.metadata = ...
        self.targets = ...
        self.batch_size = ...

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.floor(len(self.images) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return [self.images[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size], self.metadata[self.images[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]], self.targets[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]
```

It wil yield batch of data, without overflow and you can do it however you want.

And lasly, I think that `fit_generator` is deprecated and you should just go with `fit`.